# Dystopian anime series in which a boy finds a capsule, with a girl wearing a bracelet

Tags: story-identification, anime, dystopia

I remember watching something years back; the anime is set in a dystopian Japan, where a boy accidentally finds an capsule with a girl inside of it, with the girl wearing a bracelet.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: I recommend you look at the guide. As of now this question is far to broad and will most likely be closed.

Comment: Googling "setting anime dystopian japan boy capsule girl bracelet" yields: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin:_Spirits_of_the_Past, though the girl seems to have a necklace instead of a bracelet. Is the dystopian Japan in the anime you're looking for covered in trees?

Answer (score 1):

I would need more details, but it may be Origin: Spirits of the Past.

Comment: Instead of a bracelet, she has a collar device that works as a phone and other tech devices.